# I want to stop access on specific directory under hosting

Tags: hosting, file-permissions

As I am working on downloading site under woocommerce. 
today I checked anyone can get access on my wp-content directory. 
https://matrixspecialists.com/wp-content/uploads/

can anybody suggest me how can i stop this access.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open .htaccess file add this line `Options -Indexes` this will give a 403 forbidden error, you can add `Error 403 http://yoursite` in htaccess to redirect users who tried to view this directory